# How do you translate this phrase 「ボルシアは秋にイブラこと」? (see sentence for context)

Tags: translation, nominalization

The full sentence is 「ボルシアは秋にイブラことイサクという選手をエクアドルで獲得したそうである。」

The general parsing I have right now is 「ボルシアは」「秋にイブラこと」「イサクという選手をエクアドルで獲得したそうである。」

1. The topic is ボルシア (a German football team)
2. 秋にイブラこと - something pertaining to Ibra in the fall (this is tripping me up)
3. It seems that a player named Isak was acquired in Ecuador.

The only way I can get a translation to make sense in my head is to ignore (2) and go with "It seems that Borussia acquired a player called Isak", but obviously without (2) I'll be missing necessary content. Any insight into what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The key words in Japanese sentences are often very short and are written in hiragana.  In this case, it is 「こと」.

> One's nickname + こと + Original Name

means:

> [Original name] also known as [nickname]

イブラ**こと**イサク, thus means "**Isak a.k.a. Ibra**"